# Verify clicked buttons from multiple columns and display same println

Tags: java, eclipse, button, click, verify

When a button in Column A or B is clicked, it displays either "0" and "1". I'd like to verify that all buttons are clicked via the Submit button. If any button in either column is NOT clicked, then the println "Please click all buttons." should be displayed.

```
    if (id==R.id.Submit){
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0; i<colA.length; i++ ){
            if (((colA[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colA[i].getText()==("1")))){
                counter++;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<colB.length; i++ ){
            if (((colB[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colB[i].getText()==("1")))){
                counter++;  
            }
        }

            if((counter==colA.length) || (counter==colB.length)){
                // All buttons have been clicked
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Please click all buttons.");
            }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with if((counter==colA.length) || (counter==colB.length)). If counter is being used to total the number of buttons clicked in both colA and colB the only time that if statement will be true is when half the total buttons have been clicked. From your description that doesn't sound like the desired functionality. I agree with Merlin though it would be helpful to know what you think is not working.

Comment: I am unsure what I'm doing wrong to verify buttons from multiple columns, while displaying the same println. This is what I use to verify all buttons for one column:


if (id==R.id.Submit){
int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<colA.length; i++ ){
        if (((colA[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colA[i].getText()==("1")))){
          counter++;
        }

    }

  if(counter==colA.length){
           //all have been clicked

        }
else{
  System.out.println("Please enter all values for Column A.");

 }
}

Comment: @Victor please don't copy and past the exact same code into a comment unless you are referencing a specific line of code..like I did, otherwise it's a restatement of you question and doesn't clarify anything. Please see my answer below which illustrates the problem in my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We still need you to tell us exactly what is wrong/not working. To illustrate my point about `if((counter==colA.length) || (counter==colB.length))` not working because `Counter` holds a running total of both columns I've drawn out a small example.

```
colA colB
[]   []
[]   []
[]   []
[]   []
[]   []
```

in this example the `[]` represents a button that can be clicked, therefore `colA.length == 5` , `colB.length == 5` and subsequently `colA.length == colB.length`(I'm assuming that is always true).

Reviewing the 2 loops above they both use Counter which is initialized to 0. The first loop will iterate 5 times for colA and 5 times for colB, a total of 10 times. Considering the following example when all 10 buttons are clicked `Counter` will equal 10. `[x] = clicked []=not clicked`

```
colA colB
[x]   [x]
[x]   [x]
[x]   [x]
[x]   [x]
[x]   [x]
```

then comes the problem...

```
if((counter==colA.length) || (counter==colB.length)){
   // All buttons have been clicked
}
```

filling in the values for these variables you now see why it doesn't work.

`if((10==5) || (10==5)){
   // All buttons have been clicked
}`
See that is definitely not going to work for the case in which all buttons are clicked. it will however work for the following examples...but would be undesired functionality.

```
colA colB
[x]   []
[x]   []
[x]   []
[x]   []
[x]   []

colA colB
[]   [x]
[]   [x]
[]   [x]
[]   [x]
[]   [x]

colA colB
[]   [x]
[x]   []
[]   [x]
[x]   []
[]   [x]
```

There are about 29 other ways the if statement will evaluate to true but still not be correct.

I would recommend changing your code to look like this.

```
  if (id==R.id.Submit){
        int numClickedInA=0;
        int numClickedInB=0;
        for(int i=0; i<colA.length; i++ ){
            if (((colA[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colA[i].getText()==("1")))){
                ++numClickedInA;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<colB.length; i++ ){
            if (((colB[i].getText()==("0"))) || ((colB[i].getText()==("1")))){
                ++numClickedInB;  
            }
        }

            if((numClickedInA==colA.length) && (numClickedInB==colB.length)){
                // All buttons have been clicked
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Please click all buttons.");
            }
    }
```

doing it this way will also work if my assumption that `colA.length == colB.length` is not true. While I think this solves your problem I can't be sure because you have not confirmed that your problem is with detecting if all the buttons are clicked. For example this won;t fix any compiler errors you were receiving.